# Unable to play mp4 videos on iOS using jwplayer

Tags: ios, mp4, jwplayer

Here is my code, please help.

```
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
      playlist: [{
        sources: [{
          file: "rtmp://draco.streamingwizard.com/wizard/_definst_/demo/sample.mp4"
        }],
        image: "vtts/bbb-splash.png"
      }],
      width: 480,
      height: 270,
      type:"video/mp4"
    });
```

Comment: Please provide more information. What is wrong, what did you try to achieve. Have you looked at solutions on google, and if so what did you fine or use to write this code. This question is unclear. Provide more info please.

Comment: Getting error like..."Error loading player: No playable sources found"

Comment: This code generally looks not too good. Please check it again, and check if there;s not a different way to load files. Please add details to the question itself...

Comment: Hi Julian E...i'm very new to programming...just started basics and struck ed up playing videos successfully in IOS. Can u guide me??

Comment: You can't use RTMP on mobile.

Answer (score 2):

You're using RTMP, which is a Flash protocol. There is no Flash on any mobile device. You'll need to provide an HLS stream or MP4 fallback for mobiles.

Comment: http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1710454-configuring-multiple-sources